# translate field values based on array of translations

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, translation

I have a javascript/jquery script that I would like to change the form field values based on a hidden field value (language).

ie.  hidden field

`<input type=text id="language" hidden value="nl">`

form fields

```
<select name="Campus" id="Campus" class="form-control input-lg">
   <option value="">Select Campus</option>
</select>
<select name="Bootcamp" id="Bootcamp" class="form-control input-lg">
   <option value="">Select Bootcamp</option>
</select>
```

```
English: Select Campus
Spanish: Quiero asistir a este campus
French: Je veux rejoindre ce campus
Portuguese: Quero frequentar este campus
German: Ich möchte an diesem Campus teilnehmen
Dutch: Ik wil deze campus bezoeken

Bootcamp field
English: Select bootcamp
Spanish: Estoy interesado en este bootcamp
French: Je suis intéressé.e par ce cours
Portuguese: Tenho interesse neste bootcamp
German: Ich interessiere mich für dieses Bootcamp
Dutch: Ik ben geïnteresseerd in deze bootcamp
```

So Basically, I need to translate the text **"Select Bootcamp"** and **"Select Campus"** to the desired language based on the hidden field value.   So in the example above **'NL'** - dutch, I would like the fields translated to **"Ik wil deze campus bezoeken"** and **"Ik ben geïnteresseerd in deze bootcamp"**

I think I'd need some sort of multidimensional array that jquery can use to change on document ready?

something like this ?

```
const languageArray  = [{ code: 'nl', campus: 'Ik wil deze campus bezoeken', bootcamp: 'Ik ben geïnteresseerd in deze bootcamp' }, { code: 'en', campus: 'Select Campus', bootcamp: 'Select Bootcamp' }]
```

regards,
Craig.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.. I was half way there with the array  :)